# Explicit calculations of Lie algebra homology and cohomology

Tags: reference-request, lie-algebras, homological-algebra, computational-mathematics, lie-algebra-cohomology

Are there any textbooks/articles etc. which go through some explicit examples calculating Lie algebra homology and cohomology with coefficients in some representation (for example, the defining representation of $\mathfrak{sl}_n$, symmetric powers thereof, etc.)?

Comment: I have some examples in my lecture notes [here](https://homepage.univie.ac.at/Dietrich.Burde/coho_5.html), chapter $4$. In $4.6$ there are many computations for nilpotent Lie algebras with the trivial representation.